# LaTeX beamer beaver color theme not working

Tags: beamer

When I put `\usecolortheme{beaver}` in the preamble I get grey slides as opposed to the expected beaver color theme. If I use any other color theme, they work fine. The `beamercolorthemebeaver.sty` file is properly installed. Why is this happening? Why do all color themes work, except this one?

Could it be a color issue more than a theme color issue?

Sorry, adding sample code below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a slide example}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is that instead of having the corresponding color theme, it comes out on a scale of grays. Issue happens only with beaver color theme.

[image: the example slide]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The beaver sample in the beamer manual is mostly grey colors in the background with red text in headers.  This is also what I get from your sample code.  See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2137/15925 for uploading of images.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The above code yields red stripe and red title with `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex` and `latex→dvips→ps2pdf`.

Comment: Same that Toscho. Is not a coding problem.

Comment: Well... I guess i'll compile it somewhere else. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Your example results to a coloured frame as the picture below shows.

However your output is the result after a usage of the option `gray` of the package `(x)color`. So I guess you are using somewhere in your preamble something like this

```
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}
```

or

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I am not using that in the preamble. I'm running the same example I show above.  So, all I have in the preamble is: 

    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Montpellier}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}. When I run my example, the slide comes out in grey, as shown above.

Comment: Notice that this issue only happens for beaver color theme. I DO NOT get grey scale for the other color themes.